# QML transfer mouse ownership dynamically while mouse pressed

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, focus, mouseevent

I have an application with a **list of images** on the right side (using 
a ListView) and a **viewer** on the left. The user can drag an image from the list to the viewer, AND keep the image in the list (something similar to a preview of the list, but with drag and drop functionality).

To do that, when the user "pressAndHold" on an image from the list, I create a copy of that image and place it in front of the one from the list (I change the border so I know it's the copy one).

If I then release and click again on the copy, I am able to move the copy to the viewer, and once I release the copy, I destroy the copy and process the drop if dropped on the viewer area.

I cannot do it unless I release and click on the copy , because I am not able to transfer the "mouse ownership" from the list-image mousearea to the copy-image mousearea while mouse is onhold.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone looking for something similar, this is how I did it:
On the delegate, I added the mouse area:

```
MouseArea { // This is the mouse area on the original image-list
    id: thumbnailDelegateMA
    anchors { fill: parent }

    cursorShape: containsMouse ? (drag.active ? Qt.ClosedHandCursor : Qt.PointingHandCursor) : Qt.ArrowCursor

    property var copyThumbnail: undefined
    drag.target: copyThumbnail ? copyThumbnail : null

    onPressAndHold: {
        if(!copyThumbnail){
            copyThumbnail = createThumbnailCopy(imageID, parent)

            parent = copyThumbnail
            anchors.fill = copyThumbnail
        }
    }

    onReleased:{
        if(copyThumbnail){
            parent = copyThumbnail.original
            anchors.fill = copyThumbnail.original

            copyThumbnail.destroy()
        }
    }
}
```

where:

```
function createThumbnailCopy(uid, cparent){
    var main_window = cparent.parent.parent;
    var mapPos = mapFromItem(main_window, cparent.x, cparent.y);

    var thumbnailCopy = thumbnailCopyComponent.createObject(
                main_window,
                {   "original": cparent,
                    "id": uid
                    "x": mapPos .x,
                    "y": mapPos .y
                });
    return thumbnailCopy;
}
```

And:

```
Component{
    id: thumbnailCopyComponent

    Image {
        id: thumbnailCopy

        property string id;
        property var original: undefined

        Drag.hotSpot: Qt.point(width/2, 0)
        Drag.active: true

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "image://thumbnailProvider/" + id
    }
}
```